# Tap UITabBarItem with EarlGrey

Tags: ios, swift, earlgrey

Im running into a problem trying to write UI tests using Earl Grey, specifically how to perform a tap on a certain UITabBarItem.

I noticed that tab bar items don't allow for accessibility ID's and labels to be set in the storyboard, and I've tried setting the accessibility label at runtime using `barItem.accessibilityLabel = "label"` but that does not work when referencing the item using `EarlGrey.select(elementWithMatcher: grey_accessibilityLabel("label")).perform(grey_tap())`

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: were you able to find the UITabBarItem in the hierarchy printed by `[GREYElementHierarchy hierarchyStringForAllUIWindows]` ? Were you able to find any attributes there?

Comment: @gran_profaci Yes I can locate them in the hierarchy, and I see the labels that I set listed next to `AX=<attribute>`. From the documentation I can see that when this is the case, the element must be found by other means. I can use the `grey_kindOfClass` matcher, but since I have multiple tabs with no labels, how do I select a specific item of that class?

Comment: Are there no accessibility attributes at all on the elements themselves? You should probably get those added. I'd recommend using `atIndex` to find the element from the list of matched elements. However, we do not guarantee that the order will be the same every time.

Comment: @gran_profaci My apologies, Im relatively new to iOS development so Im trying to sort all this out. Im adding the accessibility attributes to the `UITabBarItems` at runtime in my `UITabBarController`. I loop through the items that I get when calling `tabBar.items!`, and call `barItem.accessibilityLabel = "label"`, `barItem.accessibilityIdentifier = "label"`, and `barItem.isAccessibilityElement = true` on each item. The view hierarchy printed in the console only shows my attributes under the `AX=<attribute>` key, but nowhere else.

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52827294/earlgrey-is-slow-when-accessing-navbar-tabbar-items/53359046#53359046), you can use this matcher to find the tab bar element.

**Matcher example**

```
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_text(tabbarTitle))
    .inRoot(grey_kindOfClass(UITabBar.self))
    .perform(grey_tap())
```

Comment: This approach stopped working on iOS 13, any ideas?