# Earlgrey is slow when accessing NavBar/TabBar Items

Tags: ios, swift, earlgrey

As EarlGrey runs in the process and there is no install/uninstall process involved as in XCUI test framework, I expected tests to run faster but I noticed it is almost the same speed as XCUI test framework. Any reasons?

It's very slow to get TabBar or NavBar items. How can I speed up the process?

I'm using this for TabBar elements to match

```
let tabButtonMatcher: GREYMatcher = grey_allOf([grey_accessibilityLabel("Something"), grey_accessibilityTrait(UIAccessibilityTraitButton),  grey_sufficientlyVisible()])
        EarlGrey.selectElement(with: tabButtonMatcher).perform(grey_tap()).assert(grey_sufficientlyVisible())
```

Similar for NavBar buttons also

```
    let navMatch: GREYMatcher = grey_allOf([grey_accessibilityID("Something"), grey_accessibilityTrait(UIAccessibilityTraitButton), grey_sufficientlyVisible()])
    EarlGrey.selectElement(with: navMatch).perform(grey_tap())
```

Comment: What matcher are you using?

Comment: Edited the question with the matchers

Comment: Can you check with grey_sufficientlyVisible() removed from the matcher?

Comment: No difference. Is there any way to just go directly to UINavBar or TabBar items? Also it prints as in the hierarchy, but I can't use UITabBarButton or UITabBarItem with grey_isKindOf    "<UITabBarButton:0x7fb37f741ee0; AX=Y; AX.label='Something'; AX.frame={{168.00000000596046, 814}, {77.999999988079054, 48}}; AX.activationPoint={207, 838}; AX.traits='UIAccessibilityTraitButton,UIAccessibilityTraitSelected'; AX.focused='N'; frame={{168.00000000596046, 1}, {77.999999988079068, 48}}; alpha=1>"

Comment: You can. I don't see any reason not to tbh.

Answer (score 4):

You must remove `grey_sufficientlyVisible` from your matchers because it doesn't make sense. This matcher is guaranteed to work well in the `assert` statement, but it seems it's inefficient to pass as a matcher parameter.

EarlGrey interacts with touch events on the run loop and, generally, it interacts with the application as well as a real user. Its unlikely tests will be fast in this case, especially compared with KIF which calls selectors on UI elements instead of passing touch events. That's not bad, it's an expected behavior for functional tests. By the way, you could speed up tests by disabling animations:

```
GREYTestHelper.enableFastAnimation()
```

Regarding your question related to matchers, I would suggest you try several approaches and find one which is suited in your case.

At first sight, it should be worth to just find a `UITabBarItem` using `grey_kindOfClass`.

**Matcher example (not working)**

```
grey_allOf([grey_kindOfClass(UITabBarItem.self), grey_text(title)])
```

But it's not the working solution.
Let's see on view hierarchy:

[image]

So if you rely on `UITabBarItem` it doesn't work, because there is no such element. You can see, that there is a private UIKit class called `UITabBarButton` which is not supposed to interact with. Moreover, it's not a subclass of `UIButton`, but it's a subclass of `UIControl`

Instead, I would recommend to select element on `UITabBar` using `inRoot` function.

**Matcher example (working)**

```
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_text(tabbarTitle))
        .inRoot(grey_kindOfClass(UITabBar.self))
        .perform(grey_tap())
```

In this case, you find an element, which has the expected text and which is located on the `UITabBar`.

For selection elements on the navigation bar it's possible to use variations of this matcher:

**Matcher example to find the element on navigation bar**

```
EarlGrey.selectElement(with: grey_kindOfClass(UIButton.self))
        .inRoot(grey_kindOfClass(UINavigationBar.self))
```

Comment: I will try this and see if it improves and accept the answer.

Comment: @user1165756 please update when you get the result 

Comment: Very small improvement, but will keep these tips in mind.